# How to convert DatetimeArray to list?

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to convert `DatetimeArray` instance `arr` to `list`.
I've tried `arr.to_list()`, which gives:

```
'DatetimeArray' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

The higher level outcome I'm trying to achieve is, I have this `df` with a column `dt` that are pandas timestamps. I want to get a list (or anything I can iterate over) of the unique `df.dt`, and also prepend to that list another timestamp `another_dt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `list()`:

```
dta = pd.arrays.DatetimeArray(pd.DatetimeIndex(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02']), freq='D')
print(list(dta))

# Output
[Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-01-02 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: wow, thanks. never occured to me to try the more primitive `list()`. wonder why pandas didn't just add `tolist` in the first place

Comment: There are some curious things with Pandas sometimes :-). An Index can't use `add`, `sub`, etc while a `Series` can but a `Series` can't use `intersection`, `union`...